# how do you select a text in javascript

Tags: javascript, highlight

Im trying to test a feature with automation tool, cypress. As it does not allow selection of text by default, I need to do it in JS.

I want to select a word from a sentence and do some styling with it.
Example : "This is a text" . 
When I highlight a word 'text', the tool bar for 'B, I, U' shows up.
So now I want to programettically want to highlight some text so that I can click on tool bar to do some styling of the text selected.

Any idea how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Please post the code you have used to try and solve this problem so that we can help you with it.

Comment: You may Look here on already solved answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Answer (score 0):

I have found JS functions for bold and italics.
**str** stands for the selected text:

```
str.bold();
str.italics();
```

Comment: I want to just highlight/select the text. Bold and italics I want to do by clicking the tool bar

Comment: I type some text in a field
cy.get('.ql-editor').type('check quill text');

Now I want to select some text

cy.get('.ql-editor').select('text'); // this is what I want to through javascript code

 and then bold it using the element in tool bar
cy.get('.ql-bold').click();

Comment: basically I jut want to highlight some text so that that styling tool bar shows up